# Error: Transport config "Smtp" is missing in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, email, cakephp-3.0

Transport config "Smtp" is missing in cakephp 3.x

I have tried some of the configuration which are as follows:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'xxxxx',
    ],
],

'Email' => [
    'default' => [
        'from' => array('site@localhost' => 'Data Mining'),
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',           
    ],
],
```

And i have used below code to send email.

```
$mail = new Email('default');

$mail->emailFormat('html');
$mail->template($template, null)->viewVars(array('body' => $mailBody));
$mail->to($email_to);
$mail->subject($subject);
$mail->replyTo(Configure::read('config.NOREPLY_EMAIL'));

$headers = array(
    'X-MC-MergeVars' => '{"NAME": "Khushang", "REGARDS":"Khushang"}',
    'X-MC-Template' => 'test-by-Khushang'
);

$mail->setHeaders($headers);
$mail->send();
```

Thank you so much...

Comment: Maybe your must use class `CakeEmail` instead of `Email`

Comment: In newer version of cakephp 3.x, there is no class like CakeEmail. It is replaced by Email.

I have used CakeEmail and it will give me this error. 
    Error: Class 'App\Controller\CakeEmail' not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving `transport` config as `Smtp` in `Email` but you have not defined it in `EmailTransport` config.

Either set `'transport' => 'Smtp',` to `'transport' => 'default',`

OR

Set `'default'` under `'EmailTransport'` to `'Smtp'`

Comment: Solved. I need to set first configuration that 'transport' => 'default'. Thank you so much for your knowledge and approach.

Comment: We need to define Smtp in Classname of EmailTransport config. And i have doing this only and it works fine. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

***Cakephp 3x set to app.php in config folder***

```
'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
           'className' => 'Mail',
           // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
           'host' => 'localhost',
           'port' => 25,
           'timeout' => 600,
           'username' => 'user',
           'password' => 'secret',
           'client' => null,
           'tls' => null,
           'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
        'mailjet' => [
           'host' => 'smtp.xxxxxxx.com',
           'port' => 465,//your ssl or none ssl port no
           'username' => 'xxxxxxxxxx', //your smtp mail id
           'password' => '***************', //your email password
           'timeout' => 60,
           'secure' => 'ssl',
           'tls' => false,
           'className' => 'Smtp'
        ]
     ],
```

***Your Controller page***

```
$email = new Email();
  $email->transport('mailjet');
   $email->from($from)
         //->attachments(TICKET_PDF . $file)
         ->to($to)
         ->emailFormat('html')
         ->subject($subject)
         ->viewVars(array('msg' => $message))
         ->send($message);
```